# I want to increase and decrease quantity label text on click on image (up down arrow .PNG) using JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, jscript

I'm creating a E-Com website and looking to change quantity on click of 
        (like up down arrow PNG) image using JavaScript.
        as you can see in following image i have put link but i need image 
        instead 
        of that and on click of that image i want to change text of that 
        Quantity label like plus and minus the quantity.
        I'm less friendly with JavaScript so kindly suggest me some way to do it 
        using JavaScript, any help would be appreciated..
        Thanks .

[image: Kindly have a look]

```
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3 id="h3" runat="server" style="font-size: 26px; color: 
         #F67777;">
        </h3>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSalePrice" runat="server" Style="font-size: 
        18px"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMrp" runat="server" Style="font-size: 18px; 
        text-decoration: line-through;"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDiscount" runat="server" Style="font-size: 
        18px; color:green; margin-left:5px"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Quantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity : " 
        Style="font-size: 18px; color:green;" ></asp:Label>


        //Want to use image // 
        <asp:Label:ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Style="font-size: 18px; 
        color:green; margin-left:5px"></asp:Label><br /> 
        **<a id="prev">Decrease Quantity</a><br />
        <a id="next">Increase Quantity</a><br />**


        <label class="hvr-skew-backward">
         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class=" hvr-skew-backward"  
         runat="server" 
         Text="Place Order" Style="color: white; border:none; " 
         onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />             
         </label>
         <label class="hvr-skew-backward">
         <asp:Button ID="BtnCart" class=" hvr-skew-backward"  
         runat="server" 
         Text="Add to Cart" Style="color: white; border:none; " />
         </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why not just change the HTML to have an image there? There’s not much use for JavaScript here. Also please don’t tag things that don’t relate.

Comment: You can use the input type "number" which does exactly that. `<input type="number" name="quantity">` - On focus it also triggers the numeric keypad on mobiles.

Comment: Need javascript to change Quantity text. @Sami

Comment: Rather then input type i thought it will look good with png image @Kyra

Comment: An alternative would be using a html entity arrow, like `&#8593;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use jQuery please see this Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/9mvmpp55/

You can use images instead of anchors.
Consider using vector based icons e.g. http://fontello.com

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="set-quantity increase">Increase</a>
<a href="#" class="set-quantity decrease">Decrease</a>

<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.set-quantity', function(){
    var current_value = $('#quantity').val() > 0 ? $('#quantity').val() : 0

    if($(this).hasClass('increase')){
      var new_value = ++current_value
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('decrease')){
      var new_value = current_value == 0 ? 0 : --current_value
    }

    console.log(new_value)
    $('#quantity').val(new_value)  
    return false;
})
```

Comment: @Dhawal - glad that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

use anchor tag and image (arrow icon) inside anchor tag, so it will work like clickable image. And call your javascript function in href attribute of anchor tag

Example -

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function changeQty(qty){
        var currentQty = document.getElementById('lblSalePrice').value;
        currentQty = currentQty + qty;
        document.getElementById('lblSalePrice').value = currentQty;
    }
</script>

<a style="color:#000;text-decoration: none" href="javascript:changeQty(1)">
    <img src="images/add.png" border="0" title="UpArrow" />
</a>

<a style="color:#000;text-decoration: none" href="javascript:changeQty(-1)">
    <img src="images/add.png" border="0" title="DownArrow" />
</a>
```

Comment: Earlier answer worked for me @Amita Thanks for your valuable time.